# Massive performance loss since wildfly 19

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

Wildfly administrators and developers,

We have a big or should I say a slow problem since wildfly 19:

Our integration tests, based on arquillian are taking way too much time. (containr managed, not remote)

In each annotated class @RunWith(arquillian) between each @Test methods, arquillian is waiting, from 20 up to 30 seconds, to start the next test. Without any logs output inbetween.

When we switch the wildfly version to 18, it's not waiting anymore the tests are executed without "break" (with the same code, Java 11, ...). So the problem happend only since the version 19, 20, 21.

We looked in every possible direction, readed again the wildfly and arquillian documentations, checked everything we could think of, but without sucess.

Does anybody experienced the same or has an idea of what's going on since version 19?

Source code is opensource, but only productive Version, so the migration is not yet there published: https://github.com/dvbern/kiBon

Thanks a lot and cheers,
Frédéric

Comment: *"We looked in every possible direction [...]"* So what do the thread dumps tell you? They should give you an indication where the execution is hanging.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! We have a few thread in TIMED_WAITING in the JBoss instance who is used for the test, in other JVM Process I dont see anything. All Arquillian Threads (2) are in state RUNNING. But the only one I can find who are with our code related are hibernate search index update.

Comment: I'm not a stack trace expert, I just see that since wildfly 19 everything goes slower, but it's really hard to analyze as a lot of libraries are provided by Wildfly. So even with the same compiled version, in the runtime version the provided libraries are changed, and a lot come with the wildfly-core. Like Arquillian, hibernate, Guava, httpclient, ....